# Redundant procedure when using Postfix relay

Tags: postfix

I have a Postfix server with the following `main.cf` file (I'll show just the relevant info):

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_relay
```

Right now everytime I want to relay the messages from one domain through my relay server I need to add the data to both `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` and `/etc/postfix/sender_relay`files:

**/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd**

```
@example.com myuser:mypass1234
```

**/etc/postfix/sender_relay**

```
@example.com [relay.example.com]:587
```

And this seems very redundant to me.

---

**My Question**

I would like to know if there is a way to use only the `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` file, and define a global `relayhost = [cluster.securitybox.cl]:587` and tell Postfix that if the domain is listed in the `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` file use that global relay, and don't use any relay if it isn't. Or any other option where I dont't have to write data into separate files.

It seems to be possible according to the [Postfix Documentation](http://www.postfix.org/SOHO_README.html)

> If you are creative, then you can try to combine the two tables into one single MySQL database, and configure different Postfix queries to extract the appropriate information.